# Can someone explain the attributes of <pending_xref> tag?

Tags: python-sphinx

I noticed that after upgrading to sphinx 6.1.3, there's a default value for attribute `refdoc` in pending_xref tag.
https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/pull/9685
What does `refdoc` and the other attributes means?

Example:

```
<pending_xref py:class="BlobClient" py:module="azure.storage.blob.aio" refdoc="azure.storage.blob.aio" refdomain="py" refspecific="False" reftarget="str" reftype="class">
```

Run sphinx 6.1.3 in local.